# Why are there so many different encryption algorithms?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Taking a quick look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography_standards), there happens to be a vast amount of different encryptions/cryptographic algorithms. Yet, many of the listings show that these encryption methods are not in use today (due to many being too weak and inefficient)...

As some encryption algorithms are more popular than others, why was not there a conformity for certain algorithm(s) to be used?

Comment: There are standards for which encryption algorithms are acceptable in certain situations.

Comment: I think that if you look at some of those pages, you'll see why there are so many. Some have specific use cases. Some get replaced by better ones as they develop. I'm not sure what you're asking that isn't evident in the link you provided.

Comment: @schroeder Makes sense. Was also wondering if there is a law governing specific standards needed for an encryption algorithm (eg. so companies do not store passwords in plaintext)? Off topic, but trying to gain some reputation as I am new and do not know of a good way to do so.

Comment: The best way to build reputation is to provide great answers. Take a look at what makes a good answer here and tackle new and unanswered questions.

Comment: As for "laws", there are no laws for this kind of thing. That would be a little crazy when, as you have seen, new approaches emerge all the time. And passwords are not encrypted (they are hashed).

Comment: Yes, there are standards for cybersecurity, such as NIST, ISO-27000, PCI-DSS, and FFIEC.

Comment: @JohnWu I do not believe the standards are legally obligatory as what schroeder pointed out. Thanks for listing the standards though, as I am unfamiliar with some you mentioned :)

Comment: @schroeder Regarding building reputation, unfortunately, I was unable to comment and needed a minimum of 15. Curious of why that is, yet anyone can answer questions..

Comment: Sort of. PCI-DSS is legally obligatory in that you are violating your merchant terms (which are in a legal contract) if you are not compliant. FFIEC is legally obligatory in that you must comply to be FDIC-insured. NIST and ISO may be obligatory if you are under a military or government contract. We are not talking about criminal law here, but contractual and civil obligations.

Comment: Because when you answer, the whole thread gains visibility, and any inappropriate posts also get visibility. Comments do not bring the same visibility, so there is a rep point threshold to prevent things like spam.

Comment: You may as well ask why are there so many programming languages, operating systems, processor types, etc, etc.  The answer is that restricting any such thing to one stifles innovation and is the way of the dictator.

Comment: @Chenmunka Not exactly. The reason for so many programming languages, operating systems, processor types, etc, is not exactly the same from why are there so many different encryption algorithms. There are many similarities however as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there are so many different encryption algorithms is the same reason there are so many different character encodings, date/time formats, chat applications, etc.

## Different people inventing similar things

A lot of duplicate work is done because different people work on similar things. Encryption algorithms are no different.

The Advanced Encryption Standard process, for example, had 15 candidates. 15 different groups of expert cryptographers were all given the same task, and so came up with 15 different algorithms. Even if there can be only one winner, that means 14 algorithms were designed, specified, probably implemented too, and never adopted.

## Distrust of other people's work

Certain organizations, such as the military, may distrust the work done by other nations. As a result, these groups either develop their own algorithms or task someone they trust with doing so.

It's no surprise that Soviet engineers didn't trust American algorithms and vice versa, so it is only natural that such competing nations/organizations/groups would not trust the work done by others and develop their own, even if the resulting algorithm may end up being inferior.

## Cryptography improves

Unsurprisingly, humanity's knowledge of cryptography keeps improving. We find new vectors of attack that render previously thought-to-be-secure algorithms vulnerable, thus necessitating the development of new algorithms.

## Not everyone has the same needs

Not everyone encrypts data for the same purpose. Top-secret documents, which need to remain uncrackable for the end of time, have different needs than a couple of bits decrypted on ultra-low energy hardware.

Some algorithms are designed to be as "general-purpose" as possible, while others aim to fulfill a very specific niche or exhibit other desirable properties (e.g., extreme energy efficiency).